# winforms - messagebox in MDI form is showing multiple times before application is closed

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, mdi

I know that there are examples of the similar problem even here in StackOverflow but I have difficulties to understand the nature of the problem and thus - to solve my custom case.

What I have right now is this code:

```
bool closingPending = false;
private void MyFormN_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (closingPending) return;
            //DialogResult answer = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes ?", "Save",
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes ?", "Save",
                                   MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,
                                   MessageBoxIcon.Information,
                                   MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button3) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                closingPending = true;
                MessageBox.Show("To Do - validate and save");
            }
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes ?", "Save",
                                   MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,
                                   MessageBoxIcon.Information,
                                   MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button3) == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                closingPending = true;
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes ?", "Save",
                                   MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,
                                   MessageBoxIcon.Information,
                                   MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button3) == DialogResult.No)
            {
                closingPending = true;
                 Application.Exit();
            }
        }
```

It's a result from my attempts and some ideas I got from other posts here. But what happens when I'm executing this code is - by pressing the `[x]` of the window i get the messagebox shown but no matter which button I click the form is shown several times. Before adding `closingPending` I'm pretty sure that this problem occurred only when I was trying `Application.Exit()`. The `closingPending` exmple worked when I try this example:

```
if(closingPending) return;
if (MessageBox.Show("This application is closing down because of " + e.CloseReason.ToString() + ". Do you really want to close it ?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
    {                
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        closingPending = true;
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

However I got some idea on what cause the problem but I'm still far away from understanding it completely or solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like below... it will solve your problem....

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes ?", "Save",
                                   MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,
                                   MessageBoxIcon.Information,
                                   MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button3);

            switch (result)
            {

                case DialogResult.Yes: 
                    closingPending = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("To Do - validate and save");
                    break;

                case DialogResult.No: 
                    closingPending = true;
                    Application.Exit();
                    break;

                case DialogResult.Cancel:
                    closingPending = true;
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, Pandian. Fast and accurate.